# Crop Image in Aspect Fill UIImageView

Tags: c#, objective-c, math, xamarin

I have been trying to figure this out for hours with no answer.

I have an UIimageView with the ContentMode as `UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill` which I would like to crop using an overlying resizable frame. The cropping frame no longer maintains a 1:1 relationship between the bounds that contains both the UIimageView and cropping tool. The cropping usually would be as simple as:

```
using (var imageRef = image.CGImage.WithImageInRect(frame)) { 
    return UIImage.FromImage(imageRef);
}
```

But, the calculations are required in the case, how would I calculate the offset to match the cropping tool frame to the newly inflated UIImageView (or rather UIImage)? Here's a image to help paint the picture:

[image: cropping tool frame]

This picture shows a few key things.

**Upper Right Image**: What will be cropped currently (area contained in blue section)

**Blue Rectangle**: Where the cropping is currently being taken place, notice the position and height is skewed compared to red.

**Red Rectangle**: The cropping control, essentially where the cropping should be taking place. INSTEAD of where blue is.

**Upper Blue Textbox**: Ignore this.

Essentially, I want the blue rect to be where the red frame is.

Any help would be greatly appeciated, I am using C# for this, but Objective C answers are more than welcomed.